# UIWebview content according to webview frame

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, ipad

I want to disable the scroll inside UIWebview and need to display content according to the width and height of UIWebview. If the content is large enough to be displayed on the page, it should display ... at the end of the text like that in UILabel.

The flipboard application has done it properly where they are displaying a part of the content on the first page and as we pinch zoom it, more content is shown on the view according to the height and width.

How this can be achieved. Any help on this is appreciated.

Sample:

I am loading this on iPad

```
UIWebView *mWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 730)];
mWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
mWebView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
mWebView.autoresizingMask=YES;
mWebView.delegate = self;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled= NO;
[self.view addSubview:mWebView];
[mWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.washingtonpost.com/c.jsp;jsessionid=E6B119C6EF5A6274030E7B3A9F97D374?item=http%3a%2f%2fwww.washingtonpost.com%2fpolitics%2fobama-gop-leaders-said-to-discuss-new-debt-plan%2f2011%2f07%2f21%2fgIQAT81BSI_mobile.mobile&cid=578815"]]];
[mWebView release];
```

I want to show only that much content that can be displayed on the frame 500,750. As you can see in the screenshot the last line is cut.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To disable the scroll of UIWebView :

```
mWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 390)];
mWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
mWebView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
mWebView.autoresizingMask=YES;
mWebView.delegate = self;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled= NO;
```

Then add this UIWebView as subview your main UIView or wherever u want.

Whenever the data is reloaded the following delegate method of UIWebView is called. So implement the dynamic resizing code inside that.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
   float webHeight;
   CGRect frame = webview.frame;
   frame.size.height = 1;
   webview.frame = frame;
   CGSize fittingSize = [webview sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
   frame.size = fittingSize;
   webview.frame = frame;
   webHeight=fittingSize.height;
   rowHt=webHeight;
   [aTableView reloadData];
}
```

I have added the UIWebView inside the tableview. So I am calling the reloadData for the tableview and passing the webHeight (new webview height)to the table delegate to the set the row height.Hope this helps.

Comment: iPhoneFreak, Thanks for the point. But i cannot change my view frame to fit the content. For example, suppose the size that fits for a content is 800 and i want to show that in height 400, if i display it, the text in the last line will be cut vertically. Instead i want to show a ... in the last line like that in flipboard. Hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of webView by using `UIWebViewDelegate`. in method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,(height + 30));
}
```

then set the webView frame size using that code.

Comment: Sisu, Thanks for the reply. But I dont want to increase the height or width according to content. Instead the content should be shown in the webview frame. The problem is that most of the case the text will be cut vertically in middle.

Comment: Sorry Anil Sivadas, no idea about IPad. but _webView_ wont show like UILabel (...). can u try using _UIScrollView_. Set the scrollview frame size with (100, 100, 500, 750) and add the _webView_ as scrollView **subview**.

Comment: Sisu, Thanks for the suggestion. Scrollview subview is not working.

Comment: You got the same after add UIWebView to UIScrollView? Have u set the scrollView content size ?

Answer (score 0):

Flipboard reformats data before presenting it. To get the same effect you will need to do the same. i.e. Read in the HTML, separate out the components and present it in your own format either via a UIWebview with HTML & CSS or in UIKIT.

UIWebviews don't support overflow with elipsis natively.  If you go down the CSS route check out the overflow property it supports elipsis.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily done using javascript.
Here i can give you an idea rest is you have to implement. place any tag lets say div tag in your html at appropriate place and put some info pinch here for continue reading once the user click on that load the next div which will have another page info. it like open the box when we really want to see. you can easily do it with javascript.